# Multilevel integer programming

Tags: optimization, integer-programming, discrete-optimization, mixed-integer-programming

Recently, I have been dealing with an integer program that involves finding a $4$-level integral solution

$$x \in \{-2, -1, 1, 2\}$$

or even $x \in \{\pm n, \pm n-1, \dots, \pm 1\}$ which is multilevel integers solution. The cost function is quadratic and $x$ is the only optimization variable.

I search the network but I could not find useful information about this kind of problem. So is there any reference (algorithm) for solving this kind of problem? Could anyone provide some suggestions? Thanks in advance!

---

Add constraint:

$x \in \{1, -1, +1i, -1i\}$ or with even more levels with unitary amplitude $|x| = 1$.

Comment: Does every level need to appear in the solution?

Comment: @RobPratt Yes, there is another constraint that $\sum_i x_i = 0$ hence every pair of $\pm n$ needs to be in the solution

Comment: @standerQiu Yet, your $4$-level example is missing $0$.

Comment: Well, $\sum_i x_i =0$ does not imply that.  For example, $-4+1+3=0$, without any $\pm 2$.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Yes, because only non-zero values are involved in my situation.

Comment: @RobPratt Thanks for your comment. I have edited the question and make the constraint more clearly: $|x_i| = 1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to restrict $x$ to a discrete set $\lbrace a_1,\dots,a_n\rbrace$ is to create $n$ binary variables $z_1,\dots,z_n$ and add the constraints $$x=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i z_i$$ and $$\sum_{i=1}^n z_i =1.$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it seems that you transfer the problem to mixed integer programming? Is there any algorithm for this problem? Sorry for lacking background in discrete optimization.

Comment: Yes, it is a mixed-integer linear program, and there are quite a few solvers available for MILPs. There are open-source solvers and commercial solvers (some with free academic licenses). You can get them with a variety of interfaces, including various high level modeling languages (where you express you model more or less in algebraic notation), APIs for programming languages (C/C++, Java, Python, MATLAB, Julia, R, ...) or via plugins to Excel, OpenOffice/LibreOffice Calc etc. A better forum on which to ask might be https://or.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Thank you very much!